check number row is equal to 10 with same value
I would like to check number of row is equal 10 with same value.
I insert the value like that
INSERT test (value) SELECT 'AAA' AS value FROM seq_1_to_10;

and i want to check the number of value is equal to 10 row in sql, but I want in mariadb

DO \$\$ DECLARE cp int; BEGIN SELECT count(*) INTO cpt FROM test WHERE value = 'AAA'; IF cpt != 10 THEN RAISE 'cpt'; END IF; END \$\$;

I am looking for in equivalent the query in mariadb
I have got this error :

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
near '$$ DECLARE cp int; BEGIN SELECT count(*) INTO cpt FROM test
WHERE value = '...' at line 1


can you reproduce the problem here https://dbfiddle.uk/OqOt74XH , because i don't have such a problem

This is only possible in a stored procedure.

@Barmar why do you say that?

@ysth Because you can't use IF statements outside procedures.

thanks fotr your replies, but I have got this error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '$$ DECLARE cp int; BEGIN SELECT count(*) INTO cpt FROM test WHERE value = '...' at line 1

@Barmar oh, thought your "this" meant the question, not their attempt

@Barmar MariaDB has added the feature of running compound statements outside procedures. https://mariadb.com/kb/en/using-compound-statements-outside-of-stored-programs/ Yet another case of MariaDB <> MySQL.

thanks Bill, I was getting it working before commenting on that :)

there is a DO in mariadb, but it has nothing to do with what you are trying; where did you see something suggesting it?

Unless you have disabled the sequence storage engine, your insert will work as is.
Alternatively you can use a recursive cte:
insert test (value)
  with recursive c as (select 1 value union select value+1 from c where value < 10)
  select 'AAA' from c

If you want to check the number of existing rows first, you do need a compound statement, but your syntax is not correct; here's an example, adjust to suit:
BEGIN NOT ATOMIC
  DECLARE c int default 10;
  SET c = c - (select count(*) from test);
  WHILE c > 0 DO
    INSERT test (value) VALUES ('AAA');
    SET c = c - 1;
  END WHILE;
END

fiddle

How do you want to do the test?  In the app?  In a stored proc?
Do you want exactly 10?  10 or more?
In a stored proc:
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @ct FROM test WHERE val = 'AAA';
IF (@ct = 10) THEN
    ...
ENDIF

In app:
...("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test WHERE val = 'AAA');  # perform the query
... get the one row of output into $ct
if ($ct == 10) ...

